# Unity Admob plugin; The application crashes when you try to change "TextMesh.text"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

1) I used the sample project on https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity
2) I added a "TextMesh" object to the scene (Game object name: "Screen Text").
3) I have added the following lines;

```
public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    TextMesh screenText;
...
...

public void Start()
{
    screenText = GameObject.Find("Screen Text").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
...
...

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    screenText.text = "Test 1";
...
...

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
{
    screenText.text = "Test 2";
...
...
```

4) When the video is finished or canceled, I'm trying to change the text and the app is always crashes.
5) Unity Version: Unity 2017.3.1f1 (64-bit). Android SDK: Platform 27. Phone Note 5

Is this an issue? or do I have to fix something?

(Here is Log file when video rewarded: https://justpaste.it/7b1hn)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, yes, it happens regularly. It's not a simple missing reference issue.

I have also tried creating a Canvas with just an Image: no crash.
Then I have tried creating a Canvas with just a TextMeshPro text: CRASH!

The simplest fix I have found (after many many hours of tests) was to "change the text" one frame later, through a very simple coroutine starting with "yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame()".

I'm still reading and investigating, and will update here if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding check for screenText? Try this.

```
    if (screenText != null)
        screenText.text = "Test 2";
    else
        Debug.Log ("NULL screenText");
```

Comment: try adding this to both methods where you are setting screenText value.

Or directly make that variable public and assign in inspector.

Comment: Yes.. I checked. The text is already displayed when the application is first run. (I can solve this problem by using two different texts; screenText1.gameobject.SetActive(true), screenText2.gameobject.SetActive(false).. But as I said, when I try to change the texts, then app  crash.

Comment: Please check by commenting other code in both methods so you can confirm that the issue is with only textmesh.

And if app stops crashing then need to check for other code of method as i tried your way and my text replaces correctly.

Comment: I try a lot of things, but still same. I uploaded project to github. Here is link: [link](https://github.com/pedicagames/admob_demo) If you have time, you can try to run the project. Maybe the problem is on my phone. Thanks..

Comment: @sadrag 
I know it's late but I got stuck at my work.

I tried your code. It crashes at text edit on rewarded video close/reward.
Then I tried using text (Of unity's UI) instead textMesh and it worked fine.
Please try using that. let me know if that will work for you.

Comment: Yeah, like you said. I think this is just an error for "TextMesh". I also wrote to github issue. For now I will handle with other solutions. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. 
Write here if you found solution regarding textMesh or if you hear back from GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

I found answer: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start?hl=ko

We need:

```
MobileAds.RaiseAdEventsOnUnityMainThread = true;
```